# Triggering events from external class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a log class that I want to trigger events from. The event is located on my base class. As long as I make calls from within the base class, it works fine. My problem is "external" calls:

My base class:

```
public delegate void StatusUpdateHandler(object sender, object arg);

public interface IFoo
{
    event StatusUpdateHandler OnStatusChanged;
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public event StatusUpdateHandler OnStatusChanged;
}
```

My log class method (in another class):

```
public void Log(string logMessage, StatusUpdateHandler updateHandler)
{
    logEntries.Add(logMessage);

    if (updateHandler == null)
        return;
    updateHandler(this, logMessage);
}
```

Calling the method from within `Foo` works fine:

```
loggerInstance.Log("test", OnLogMessage);
```

But when I make a call from outside of the class I get this compile error:

```
void OutsideFooLog(IFoo foo)
{
    loggerInstance.Log("test", foo.OnLogMessage)
}

// The event 'OnLogMessage' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=
```

My goal here is to trigger `OnLogMessage` in `Foo` whenever I make a log entry, regardless if I log from inside or outside of the class itself. The reason why I want it as a parameter is because I have several other events.

Comment: You can't access events from other classes like that. You will have to wrap them in methods which raise the events, and use the methods as argument or something similar (e.g. use enum, and fire event from `switch` statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events can only be raised by their owning types, so your interface and implementation should publish a method, which will then raise the event when called.

You should think about concerns of your classes. The OnLogMessage event should be raised by the class whose concern is handling log messages. If you follow that rule, you should never come into that situation again.

Also especially in code examples please name your types and members something meaningful. I found it very hard to understand the motivations and responsibilities behind your example code (Foo).

Comment: Yeah I thought of the separation of concerns after posting this as well. Thanks for bringing it up